# How to force update of UI before executing AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm new to Android development. I'm executing an AsyncTask when a menu icon on the App Bar is clicked. However, the icon never shows that it has been pressed until after the AsyncTask has completed. So while the network task might task a few seconds, to the user it looks like the button does nothing.

Is there a way to force the UI to show the icon press animation before executing the task? Also a toast I have set won't get executed either until after the AsyncTask. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I ended up using a Handler with an execution delay, as suggested in the comment below by Dastan:

```
its not recommended but if still its not solving may be you can add delay Handler().postDelayed(asyncTask,400); 
//400ms animation time – dastan Feb 13 at 2:06
```

This allows the UI to update. However, I would like to find a more efficient solution.

Comment: Did you look at the onPreExecute() ?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I tried executing a Toast from onPreExecute, but no good. It doesn't show until after AsyncTask has completed.

Comment: its not recommended but if still its not solving may be you can add delay Handler().postDelayed(asyncTask,400); //400ms animation time

Comment: onPreExecute(), invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance by showing a progress bar in the user interface.

Comment: Thanks aslaleem!

Comment: dastan, your solution works! Thanks so much. Feel free to add it as a 'solution'!

Answer (score 0):

Hi welcome to android development.
1st solution : using this library for button https://github.com/medyo/Fancybuttons

2nd solution : dont run in UI thread, because it will stop drawing UI.

3rd solution : use RX library, its powerful and you dont need to wait until the process finish.

My recommendation is using 3rd solution, effective and easy to maintenance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My apologies, I meant menu icon on the App Bar not button. Sorry about that. I have now edited my post. :-/